# How to keep large SOQL query cached in Salesforce Org. for speedy returns?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

We are having an issue where we need event relations for people(s), and are having problems with this very large group of people having almost 400 total event relations in this one week we are testing on... When trying to grab this large groups event relations, it will take forever and possibly time out. However, if you try again right after a timeout it goes in a couple seconds and is great. I was thinking this was salesforce just chaching the soql query/information and so it could act very quickly the second time. I tried to kind of trick it into having this query cached and ready by having a batch job that ran regularly to query every members event relations so when they tried to access our app the timeout issue would stop.

However, this is not even appearing to work. Even though the batch is running correctly and querying all these event relations, when you go to the app after a while without using it, it will still timeout or take very long the first time then be very quick after that.

Is there a way to successfully keep this cached so it will run very quickly when a user goes and tries to see all the event relations of a large group of people? With the developer console we saw that the event relation query was the huge time suck in the code and the real issue. I have been kind of looking into the Platform Cache of salesforce. Would storing this data there provide the solution I am looking for?

Comment: You should put this in Salesforce.stackexchange

Comment: Yes, platform cache can provide the solution. Look at my [answer about platform cache](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163334/how-to-get-profile-ids-without-soql-query/163335#163335) on stack exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into updating your query to be selective by using indexes in the where cause and custom indexes if necessary.

Comment: I ended up solely relying on ActivityDate opposed to start and end date time fields, as ActivityDate is indexed while the other date fields are not. Using the query plan, the cost of my query went from about 4 to like, 0.4 after doing this.